# Report steps using TestProject Java SDK

Tags: java, sdk, test-project, testproject.io

how can I report steps in my java code using TestProject Java SDK?
Can anyone share an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the helper in order to get the reporter.

```
ActionReporter reporter = helper.getReporter();
```

Now that you have the reporter you can use it to report steps, for example:

```
 reporter.result("Step passed");
```